# CMD Copy command is not executing properly through C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I have a program where you can choose a source folder and a destiantion folder. You can also choose a type of file for example: manual*.pdf.

This program should copy the files from the source folder to the destination folder.

It creats a command for the cmd. It opens the cdm and runs the command but it stops after a few copied files.
If I run the command manually it works perfect.

I dont know what the problem is.

```
txtKopierBefehl.Text = "FOR /F \"delims=#\" %i IN ('dir /ad /b /s " +
        txtQuelle.Text + "') DO @copy \"%i\\" + txtDateiKriterien.Text +
        "\" " + txtZiel.Text + " /y";

cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.Start();

cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(txtKopierBefehl.Text);
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
cmd.StandardInput.Close();
cmd.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: You can do it, through programatically in C#, why do you want to execute the commands through C# in this case

Comment: Cause I need to get it as a .exe file.

Comment: So firing a cmd prompt to do that is a more complicated way of doing it, copy the files using c# built in commands and you can see and check whats going on far more easily

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: @BNG.exe have a look at File.Copy ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain about this but here are my thoughts:

You're doing a cmd.WaitForExit() while also having RedirectStandardOutput enabled, which means that any output in the CMD will be written to the StandardOutput stream.

Since you're waiting for the process to exit before ever reading the StandardOuput I'm guessing that the stream is filling up and eventually the process halts until the stream gets freed again.

So you will probably just have to switch the last two lines around, first do the StandardOutput.ReadToEnd and then the WaitForExit.

Otherwise, to elaborate on the comment from BugFinder, use the functionality from [System.IO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io?view=netframework-4.8) to [copy files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-copy-delete-and-move-files-and-folders).